# En Python ¿cómo puedo eliminar el salto de línea en un input al usar fstring

Tags: python

hora_inicio = input(f"Introduzca la hora más temprana de reserva (por defecto {hora_inicio}: ") or hora_inicio

El input lo hace en la siguiente línea

Comment: No puedes eliminar el salto de línea en el `input()`, sin importar si sea f-string o no.

Answer (score 1):

Ya está resuelto. El problema lo generaba yo. La variable hora_inicio la tomaba de un fichero donde tenía un salto de línea, no era un caracter que introdujera fstring